# Using CArrayDataProvider to populate a CGridView in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

```
CArrayDataProvider Object
(
    [keyField] => 
    [rawData] => Array
        (
            [24] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 24
                    [name] => trillia
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 25
                    [name] => ahestina
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 28
                    [name] => piyas
                )

            [59] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 59
                    [name] => sitesrs
                )

            [60] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 60
                    [name] => simons
                )

            [70] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 70
                    [name] => Mahesh Raj
                )

            [71] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 71
                    [name] => kathetrine
                )

            [72] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 72
                    [name] => babig
                )

            [73] => Array
                (
                    [ids] => 73
                    [name] => symons
                )



        )

    [caseSensitiveSort] => 1
    [_id:CDataProvider:private] => 
    [_data:CDataProvider:private] => 
    [_keys:CDataProvider:private] => 
    [_totalItemCount:CDataProvider:private] => 
    [_sort:CDataProvider:private] => 
    [_pagination:CDataProvider:private] => CPagination Object
        (
            [pageVar] => page
            [route] => 
            [params] => 
            [validateCurrentPage] => 1
            [_pageSize:CPagination:private] => 10
            [_itemCount:CPagination:private] => 0
            [_currentPage:CPagination:private] => 
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

from the above array i populate the cgridview , using the following code in view file

```
 <?php
                             $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                                'id'=>'unen-custom-module-grid',
                                'dataProvider'=>$unenrollProvider,
                                //'dataProvider'=>Yii::app()->globals->getUsersByStandardnSection(1,3),
                                'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-striped flip-scroll',
                                'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
                                'template'=>'{summary}{pager}{items}{summary}{pager}',
                                'pager'=>array(
                                 'header'         => '',
                                 'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;',
                                 'prevPageLabel'  => 'PREVIOUS',
                                 'nextPageLabel'  => 'NEXT',
                                 'lastPageLabel'  => '&gt;&gt;',
                                 ),
                                // 'selectableRows' => 2,
                                'columns'=>array(
                                   array(
                                     'header'=>'#',
                                     'value'=>'++$row',
                                     'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                     'style'=>'width:50px;'
                                     )
                                 ),
                                   'name',
                                   array(
                                  'id' => 'unselectedIds',
                                //  'name' => 'ids',
                                  'selectableRows' => 2,
                                  'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                                   //'value'=>'$this->ids'
                                  ),
                                ),
                             ));
                             ?>
```

its working fine , but whenever i click the pagination the cgridview is automatically hiding , im not using $model->search() here ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time cgridview pagination sends get requests only,  with out form post data you cant able to populate the cgrid again and again , so try to store the values in session and access it , i hope its usefull to you , try it

Answer (score 0):

CGridView requires the result returned by CActiveDataProvider so try to do this in your search method in the corresponding model using CActiveDataProvider

Comment: hi @ sprytechies , im using this page as a referense http://queirozf.com/entries/using-carraydataprovider-to-populate-a-cgridview-in-yii , anyway to solve the pagination issue without using $model->search()

Comment: @sprytechies that is simply not true. `CGridView` requires a `CDataProvider`. That could virtually be any data provider in Yii. `CActiveDataProvider` does allow for advanced features such as filtering and searching, though.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're experiencing a problem here for not having specified a `keyField` in your data provider. Try `array('keyField'=>'ids)` when creating the data provider instance. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082568/carraydataprovider-with-cgridview-pagination-yii).